# Export a sqlite database through drupal admin?

Tags: 7, database

I have a drupal site running on sqlite. I'd like to backup the entire sqlite db, but keep running into "reading secure data from server" issues on my server. How do I go about backing up just the sqlite db from within the drupal admin area?

Answer (score 0):

Not aware of an out of the box way to get it done in the admin area, but you shout be able to back the sql lite file up by downloading it in cpanel or ftp. There is a discussion about doing just that right here https://www.drupal.org/node/1156588